# LoadError RubyInstaller with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems

So I have tried to uninstall re-install as well as run a gem update but keep getting the errors below.

```
C:\Users\Dakota>rspec
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/
core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Users/Dakota/s
pec (LoadError)
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0
.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It seems to be looking for a file that doesn't exist. Make sure C:/Users/Dakota/spec exists (although it's strange to not have a file extension). Perhaps something went wrong in the configuration or you downloaded the wrong gem. It's possible you got the rspec gem for the wrong version of ruby that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't your app directory. You are currently in `C:\User\Dakota` when you are executing rspec. You want to be in `C:\Users\Dakota\<rails app here>` and from there you should execute rspec with `rspec spec/`. Really though you should be using bundle to do the execution so you most likely want to run `bundle exec rspec spec/`